# Как правильно купить хлеб: батон, буханка, булка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно посмотреть в словарь:

ХЛЕБ, 1. только ед. Пищевой продукт, выпекаемый из муки. Ржаной, чёрный х. Пшеничный, белый х. (Это общее название)

БУЛКА,  Белый пшеничный хлеб, обычно круглой или овальной формы.

Из этого следует, что нельзя говорить "булка хлеба", так как булка - это уже хлеб.

Смотрим дальше:

БАТОН, -а; м. [от франц. bâton - палка, жезл]. 1. Белый хлеб вытянутой формы. Нарезной б. Купить буханку хлеба и два батона.

БУХАНКА,  Целый формовой хлеб (обычно чёрный). Б. хлеба. Съесть целую буханку.

**Так как правильно?** Покупаю буханку черного (а то еще белый "кирпичик" дадут), два батона ("белого" или "хлеба" - избыточная информация) и булку с сыром (если булок много).

Получается, что буханка хлеба - это правильно, булка хлеба - ни в коем случае.

А вот  "батон хлеба" или "батон белого"? **Нельзя так говорить, это неграмотная речь или допускаемый разговорный вариант?**

Comment: Однако на северо-западе России фразу "батон белого хлеба" не понимают и обычно - переспрашивают: "Вам батон или хлеб"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу сказать только, как я сам говорю, без всяких обоснований.
Варианты:

- одну буханку / буханку чёрного и два батона / два белых
- один кирпич / кирпич белого и две буханки чёрного
- плетёнку/халу и один круглый (столичный)

Слово *булка* применительно к большому хлебу я не использую (но это не значит, что так и надо). *Батон хлеба* или *батон белого* не говорю. *Буханку чёрного* могу сказать, но скорее скажу просто *буханку* в надежде, что меня поймут. Добавляю тогда как раз, когда боюсь, что поймут неправильно.

Comment: Можно, наверное, со всем согласиться, кроме "два белых". Лучше всё-таки два батона.

Comment: Согласен, да, так лучше. Но "два белых" мне не настолько режет слух, как, например, "батон белого".

Answer (score 2):

Со всеми словарными вариантами согласен. Добавил бы к употреблению слова "булка": за семейным обедом так называют любой кусок белого хлеба, независимо от того, в виде батона или буханки он куплен ("с чем будешь есть - с хлебом или с булкой?").

*"Батон хлеба"* - для меня недопустимое выражение, хотя оно и далеко от чудовищного "булка хлеба". Если встретится экзотическое изделие (чёрный хлеб в форме батона), я и тогда уклонюсь от такого названия.

*"Батон белого*" как разговорный вариант я бы принял: здесь "батон" выступает как единица измерения покупаемого продукта, можно так сказать продавцу - напр. после упоминания нужного количества "буханок чёрного".

Comment: Если ориентироваться на единицу измерения, то все можно нормировать: где батон белого, там и два батона белого (хлеба), потом два батона хлеба, а потом и до булки хлеба дойдет.

Comment: Единица измерения у каждой сущности устоялась своя (белый хлеб - батонами, чёрный - буханками). Вот в китайском с этим полный порядок, напр. длинные предметы (собака, дорога) - одно счётное слово, парные предметы (обувь) - другое, и т. д. Это совершенно разные "штуки" как единицы измерения. У нас это в более лёгкой форме (бутылки пива, стволы оружия, буханки хлеба, головы скота).

Comment: Тогда почему  "батон хлеба"  для Вас недопустимое выражение", в то время как батон белого - допустимое.

Comment: Потому что "батон" однозначно указывает на "булку". Добавление к этому "(белого) хлеба" ставит под сомнение уже названную и точно выраженную сущность.

Answer (score 0):

Форма хлеба Рижского, Горчичного и подобных им видов чёрного позволяет говорить о ней как о батоне. Белый хлеб, как и серый, «кирпичом» следует назвать буханкой также исключительно согласно его форме. Поэтому, когда на прилавке два батона (из пшеничной и ржаной муки), не зазорно и правильно попросить **батон чёрного**, и фраза «**буханку серого** (белого), пожалуйста», при его наличии, тоже никого не должна покоробить.

Булка — небольшое изделие. Собранные (слепленные) из булок без начинки батоны и буханки тоже называют булками, и эту «неправильность» как-то можно пережить, если общая форма подразумевает деление без применения ножа. «Булка хлеба» при том, что отдельная булка бывает с начинкой, звучит странно, но точно по сути — она вся их хлеба.

Вопрос «Как правильно купить хлеб» ставит в тупик. Что-то в нём не так.

Comment: А словарь вас не ставит в тупик? Батон, булка, буханка - это не только форма, но и содержание хлеба (белый пшеничный, черный ржаной). Поэтому неправильно (согласно словарю) просить батон черного, а булкой следует называть именно булку - белую,  пшеничную, круглой или овальной формы. Все эти названия дают нам возможность быстро и правильно понимать нашу речь.

Comment: Вот почему именно "булку хлеба" здесь назвали чудовищной? Да потому, что название определяет наличие у этого хлебного изделия наибольшего количества отличительных признаков (форма, размер, цвет, мука), чтобы потом еще добавлять, что булка состоит из хлеба.

Comment: «Все эти названия дают нам возможность быстро и правильно понимать нашу речь», — говорите? Зачем же сомневаться во всеобщем понимании таких известных слов, коль скоро всем нам всё ясно? А что до вопроса «Как купить хлеб?»... Тот, кто здесь назвал «булку хлеба» чудовищным, ответил на этот вопрос? Может быть кто-то ещё ответил?

Comment: Могу привести в качестве примера свой ответ. Я считаю, что нет необходимости добавлять "хлеба" ни к одному из названий, так как и без "хлеба"  понятно, что в булочной я покупаю не колбасу. Не надо засорять речь лишними словами.

Comment: Мой ответ. Надо иметь деньги.

Answer (score 0):

У каждого хлеба есть свое название - от изготовителя или согласно стандарту. Издавна. Например, "пшеничный подовый"(он всегда круглый, ни буханкой, ни батоном уж не назовёшь), "пшеничный формовой"(смело называйте буханкой или кирпичом, если хотите), "бородинский"(всегда просят только по названию), "боярский", "российский", "зимневский"(на нашем хлебкомбинате - ржаные батоны),"батон столичный" всегда ослепительно белый, "ромашка", "хала","городская булочка"(раньше была "французской"), "сайка"(в Крыму и не только не встречал уже лет 20), "хлеб крестьянский подовый, - все из пшеничной муки, "ржаной подовый"(очень вкусный хлеб, как и его коллега "ржаной формовой" стоил при СССР 16 копеек и назывался "серым" иногда). В Мурманской области пекут "кумужинский хлеб" из смеси злаков с добавками из водорослей в виде батона. Думаю, употреблять слово "правильно" с продолжением "купить хлеб" - как раз неправильно. Не ломайте голову над вопросом, которого нет. Не знаете названия хлеба - покажите пальцем, Вас поймут.

Comment: Можно, конечно, и пальцем показать, но здесь речь не том, что Вам вместо бородинского кирпичика могут подать  ржаной батон .  Здесь обсуждался следующий вопрос: если, к примеру, кто-нибудь попросит батон хлеба "столичный" и булку хлеба "городскую", то будет ли такая речь считаться грамотной? А заголовок  вопроса, который Вам не понравился, конечно же, условный (можно сказать, газетного стиля).

Comment: Симферопольский хлебзавод выпекает "Бородинский" в виде 400-граммового батона.Смысл моего ответа - именовать хлебное изделие по названию и будет грамотно. Хотя, по моему, слово "буханка" вполне жизненно по отношению к формовому хлебу. В остальных случаях нужно говорить по названию, например "Городскую булочку, пожалуйста", либо "Хлебец диабетический" и так далее. Других вариантов не вижу.

Comment: А булки(булочки) могут быть и не белыми(пшеничными), а и ячменными, ржаными, овсяными и вообще не хлебными, а, например, из рисовой или гречишной муки.

Comment: Ну да,  вот в нашем супермаркете выпекается много собственных хлебных изделий, и  у кассира есть толстая книжечка с их фотографиями. Она смотрит на вашу булочку и никак ее не может узнать, листает и листает книжечку. А иногда спрашивает у покупателя название, а он, конечно же, ничего не помнит.  Это я к тому, что булочки бывают не только разными, а очень разными.

Comment: "булочки бывают не только разными, а очень разными. –  Vera." Конечно. Но большинство из них - всё же хлеб.

Answer (score 0):

Хлеб бывает белый и черный. Ну серый еще (для приверед). Форма хлеба может быть разная: батон, буханка, каравай... Поэтому может быть черный хлеб в виде батона и белый в форме буханки. Булка обычно сдобная, сладкая обычно из пшеничной муки (не из белого хлеба!) Сейчас могут быть сдобные, сладкие  изделия из ржаной муки. Наверно это тоже булочки?

Comment: Опечатка: не / но?

Answer (score 0):

Булка это белый хлеб высшего сорта. А батон - да, это форма такая.
Слово булка пришло из Петербурга, там по французской моде стали так называть ситный белый хлеб.

Comment: Французское слово пришло из Петербурга? А в Петербург — буханка?

Comment: из Питербулка..